# Getting an appropriate array using MySQL for PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have to show a listing of products for a store.All I have is a store id and I have to associate 6 tables to get so.
Query I have used is fetching me the records correctly but not in the desirable array format.
I don't know if the array format I want is possible or not.
My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT KR.knifename,KR.id,CAT.categoryname,KR.knifecode FROM assocknives AS AK
                                             INNER JOIN kniferegisters AS KR ON KR.id = AK.kniferegister_id
                                             INNER JOIN categories AS CAT ON CAT.id = KR.sub_category_id
                                             INNER JOIN stores AS STR ON STR.id = AK.store_id                                             
                                             INNER JOIN brands AS BRND ON BRND.id = AK.brand_id
                                             INNER JOIN assocknifeprices AS AKP ON AKP.assocknife_id = AK.id
                                             WHERE AK.store_id='.$storeId.' AND BRND.is_active ="1" AND STR.is_active ="1"
```

Which gives me the array as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [KR] => Array
                (
                    [knifename] => xxx
                    [id] => xxx
                    [knifecode] => xxx
                )

            [CAT] => Array
                (
                    [categoryname] => xxx
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [KR] => Array
                (
                    [knifename] => xxx
                    [id] => xxx
                    [knifecode] => xxx
                )

            [CAT] => Array
                (
                    [categoryname] => xxx
                )

        )

)
```

The result is correct but I want to get it as

```
Array
(
    [categoryname1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [knifename] => xxx
                    [id] => xxx
                    [knifecode] => xxx
                )

            [1] => Array
                (                   
                    [knifename] => xxx
                    [id] => xxx
                    [knifecode] => xxx
                )

        )

    [categoryname2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [knifename] => xxx
                    [id] => xxx
                    [knifecode] => xxx
                )

            [1] => Array
                (                   
                    [knifename] => xxx
                    [id] => xxx
                    [knifecode] => xxx
                )

        )
```

)
I am sorry If this seems to be a silly thing but this array format will really help my cause.
Thanks all for your attention.

Comment: Remove the `AS AK`s after the table declaration. If you want to name your tables without getting the handlers back in the results, just remove the `AS` and your query will remain functional.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Well, the data is certainly not coming in that format from the database. It's being processed by some code you're not showing...

Comment: @AleksG I tried using GroupBy and some other functions but they dont serve the purpose as they do not fetch all the products.I tried other ways also like trying to assign category name as a key but to no use.I am an old user of SO and I know I should try it myself first.

Comment: @deceze the above array is comming from the database as a result of query.

Comment: I know no PHP MySQL API that returns such a multi-dimensional array. You probably have your own database API written on top, which applies this formatting.

Comment: All I want to know if it can be done using a single sql query and manipulating it in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process the data yourself to get it Into formats similar to this. Usually you can loop through the rows and turn it into array of desired format.

Comment: Category names can be different so I need to collect them category wise.

Comment: You can set up an array as a template, then loop through the rows and add the data to the template array. It solves your problem.

Comment: Means it cant be done by manipulating a SQL query alone?

Answer (score 0):

There is one nice function(option) to get the output as you expect.. **(i.e) using array_combine()**

Use as follows,

**Get the result in one array as $arrayValue and create one new array as arrayKey with array keys as follows,**

```
    $arrayValue = SQL RESULT
    $arrayKey = array('categoryname1','categoryname2',....) 

    $expectedArrayResult = array_combine($arrayKey, $arrayValue)..

    print_r($expectedArrayResult);
```

If you need to attach with corresponding products mean use as the following function,

you need to pass category with key and the value array also with category key

```
 function combine_assoc($map, $values) {
  $output = array();
  foreach($map as $key => $values) {
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $value)) return FALSE;
    $output[$value] = $values[$key];
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: That wont exactly relate the category names to its products.

Comment: Edited my answer.. please check it out.... If its not you expect.. then please explain me litle briefly.. how the category relates to the products?

Comment: How will I get category names in a different array?

Comment: get the category name and key using one query and have it in separate array

Comment: Thanx @Vinoth but I want to do that in a single query.I do have other options too.